# Calculating derivative and integration using matlab

Tags: matlab, derivative, symbolic-integration

I am trying to find second derivative of a function, but while initializing my symbols i am getting the following error:

```
Error using ==> subsindex
Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'sym'.
```

The commands I am using are:

```
syms x a b c L;
u = (a*x(x-L))+(b*x((x^2)-(L^2)))+(c*x((x^3)-(L^3)));
```

"`u`" is my function.

Comment: got the answer, it was an error with brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about MATLAB's symbolic capabilities, but that error is coming from the pieces like

```
x(x-L)
```

which MATLAB is interpreting as an indexing operation. Did you mean multiplication there? I.e.

```
x*(x-L)
```

Comment: Oh, just seen your comment. Anyway, I'll leave the answer here because I think it spells things out more explicitly.